# IGPutilities in IGPFunctions?

Tags: arcobjects, geoprocessing, .net

In Esri's area calculation [sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Calculate_area_geoprocessing_function_tool/0001000002r6000000/) of IGPFunction implementation they use [IGPUtilities](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002n00000438000000) but they don't release the instance.

On the [singletons page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Interacting_with_singleton_objects/00010000043p000000/) in SDK help they list GPUtilities as a singleton object.  So shouldn't our instances of IGPUtilities be released? And also should we not use the Activator class to create the instance?

In a IGPFunction implemented class do people have any preference on creating a class instance of IGPUtilities (like in the Esri Area Calculator example) or create them in the methods when needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, ideally, you should use Activator to get a GPUtilities instance.

You do not need to release it, though. Once the class is instantiated, ArcObjects keep the single instance in memory. Any effort on your part to release it in .NET will only result in releasing its RCW (runtime callable wrapper), not the actual instance. Garbage collector will do that for you anyway and in this case there is no need for the RCW to be released in a timely manner, since the actual COM object will still live on until the thread which owns it terminates.

Comment: +1 Any thoughts on when [IGpUtilities.ReleaseInternals](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ReleaseInternals_Method/002n0000048t000000/) should be called?

Comment: Oh, right, perhaps the OP meant ReleaseInternals() when he spoke about releasing IGPUtilities?

Comment: I'm not sure. A long time ago I had a geoprocessing issue that I ended up resolving by calling ReleaseInternals. I'm not sure why that fixed it. "Releases all internal objects used _prior to releasing this GPUtilities object_." ... But singletons shouldn't need releasing. GpUtilities sure smells like a [God Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) to me.

Comment: Well I actually meant both ReleaseInternals and the standard Marshal.ReleaseComObject.  I started using ReleaseInternals but didn't seem to do anything, perhaps it clears the layers and temp data etc that are created in the GeoProcessor (e.g. MakeFeatureLayer etc.)  Anyway Thanks Petr, answered my question.